# How do I create an API or link to my SVG so other websites can show it?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I have a website where I create a dynamic SVG using D3.

I'd like users websites to be able to use my SVG through an API. My website takes an input from the user, and the svg is drawn when this is submitted.

What I want to show on other websites when a certain link(?) is called, is to create the SVG and have them be able to view it on their website.

What are any possible ways to achieve this?

Comment: Why can't other web sites just use your JavaScript to render?

Comment: How would they do this? I want any website to be able to use my website and then be able to show the result SVG on their own website. How would i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a page suitable to be embeded in the target page. For instance, if your svg is `640x480` and the page has no other elements, the svg element can be shown in the external page using embed:

```
<embed type="text/html" src="http://yoursite.com/embed_url" 
       width="640" height="480">
```

Note that this is not an API, it's just a portion of your page being displayed in the other page. Regards,